# htaccess Redirect 301 adds trailing slash ... want it removed

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

This is probably very basic, but I can't figure out why the heck my 301 redirect is adding a trailing slash.

I want to redirect:

http://example.com/register to https://attendee.gotowebinar.com/register/[string of numbers]

So my redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /register https://attendee.gotowebinar.com/register/[string of numbers]
```

This adds a trailing slash on the end of the redirected URL which gives me a 404.

Is there anyway I can have the 301 redirect not add the trailing slash on the end?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Redirect` directive. Use `RedirectMatch` to get precise URL:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/register https://attendee.gotowebinar.com/register/123456
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this rule.